# navbar and footer when reduce window

Tags: html, css

I have this problem when I reduce window:

---

[image]

---

This the css for nav bar and footer

**CSS**

```css
    nav{
      width: 100%;
      max-width:100%;
      min-width:1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;}
    footer {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
     text-align:center;
     width:100%;
     max-width:100%;
      min-width:1000px;
    }
```

Comment: see the picture I want my navbar to take all space when reduse window

Comment: Please post html as well and all the css related to it. Maybe the parent element is not having width as 100%.

Comment: the  navbar is in the contaner that have same proprties 
#container{
 max-width:100%;
  min-width:1000px;
  margin: 0 ;
padding:0;  
 
}

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I don't know how to integrate it here

Comment: Just write your code in js fiddle and coppy its link location here . that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Add js.fiddle link to see your html coding

Comment: please attach links for images whole page is looking blank and content instead of php code is required

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_04/Lqe654tn/) solved your isssue copy the css as it is in fiddle